# insert data into several tables with same primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables , `std_personal` and `std_education` like this :

```
std_personal :
+----------------------+
| id |  name | family  |
+----------------------+

std_education :
+----------------------+ 
| related_std |  grade |
+----------------------+
```

`std_education.related_std` must be equal to `std_personal.id`
how can I insert data in these two different tables using 1 query ?
my problem is that `std_personal.id` is not exist when I want to insert `std_education.related_std`
:)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to introduce a Foreign Key relation in std_personal?

Answer (score 2):

You can't  insert data in two tables with only 1 query.

You must first add data into your first table `std_personal`, get the primary key generated and then insert data into your second table `std_education`  with this primary key

You may want to introduce the foreign key concept.

Answer (score 1):

you should either use a stored procedure or use 2 inserts and 1 select commands.

first

```
 insert into std_personal (id,name,family) values(1,'testname','testfamily')
```

second

```
 select id from std_personal where name ='testname' and family ='testfamily'
```

third

```
 insert into std_education (related_std ,grade) values(id_returned_from_db, 'A+')
```

OR write a stored procedure to do these three steps with one call from PHP

here is the stored procuder

```
 Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[TWO_INSERTS_WITH_ONE_WUERY]      
                                              (@name nvarchar(50),@surname nvarchar(50),@grade nvarchar(3))
 AS
 BEGIN

 declare @id int;

 insert into std_personal (id,name,family) values(1,@name,@surname)

 select @id=id from std_personal where name =@name and family =@surname

 insert into std_education (related_std ,grade) values(@id, @grade)


 END



 GO
```

Comment: he wants to insert data in one query

Comment: it is impossbile. can you do it?

Comment: why its not possible with one query?

Comment: @su It's impossible without using a stored procedure, it's the way sql works.

Comment: I will write a strod procedure. please wait

Comment: this solution is similar to what I use now , but I think there is a way to do it by one query .
I have tried some sub queries like this
`insert into std_education(...) values(select id from std_personal)`
but I couldn't solve it

Comment: and also I thinks maybe trans actions are useful for this but I cant do some thing especial .
:(

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your schema you have one piece of personal data and only one pece of educational data. Typically there would be multiple education records for an individual.  With that in mind you should be using a one-to-many relationship between std_personal and std_education. If you do that you should

- Start a transaction
- insert into std_personal
- get the primary key
- insert into std_education using the personal primary key as a foreign key
- end transaction

You would use a try catch block and rollback if any error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that in one query,i don't think it's possible but may you do like this,

first insert data into **std_personal**

```
insert into std_personal (id,name,family) values(0,'name','family');
```

then get  id from last record  in table **std_personal**

```
select id from std_personal order by id desc  limit 1;
```

finally insert data into std_education.

```
insert into std_education (related_std ,grade) values(id_from_select, 'grade');
```